# Reduce spawn process execution time from seconds to miliseconds in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, spawn

I want to execute python code in Node js application so I used below

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const process = spawn('node', ['-c', "python code content will come here"]);
process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Its working as expected but taking around seconds to print the output in **stdout**,
some python scripts return data in large amount so i used **process.stdout**

Now my main concern is time , how I can reduce this time which should be in miliseconds but taking seconds to execute and print the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips to improve performance when running Python scripts from a Node.js application:

- Use Python scripts instead of inline code: Instead of passing the Python code inline (i.e., in the `spawn command`), you should save it as a `.py` file and run the file using the Python interpreter. This way, Python can use its built-in optimizations for loading and running scripts, which are not available when running inline code.
- Use a faster Python interpreter: If you're using standard CPython, you might try a faster interpreter like PyPy, which often runs Python code much faster thanks to its Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler. You can fine more [here](https://realpython.com/pypy-faster-python/)
- Parallelize your Python code: If your Python code is CPU-bound, and if it's possible to divide the work into independent tasks, you could potentially use Python's multiprocessing module to run code in parallel and make use of all your CPU cores.
- Use streams: If the Python script produces a large amount of output, consider using streams to process the data as it arrives, rather than waiting for the entire data set to be produced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem lately - I had a trained model that has a Python inference + Node.js app which uses this model and serves as an API. The python process recognises the image content.

I realised it might be related to one of these reasons:

- spawning the terminal with Node.js process
- the Python code (including imports)

Regarding the 1st - your computer needs to allocate some memory for this process to heat it up. Good thing here is that it needs to do it only once, so you can start the terminal and then reuse the stdout outputs. I've created an example [gist here](https://gist.github.com/goodwin64/7613f26b87140f4462f9fae9eacb7afb) but I'll copy it below as well:

```ts
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

import {
  pythonRunningProcess,
  spawnPythonProcess
} from './spawn-python-process';
import {
  useRunningPythonServer
} from './use-running-python-server';

const downloadsFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');

let isProcessing = false;
const requestQueue: Array < {
  filePath: string;
  res: any; // Express response
} > = [];

async function processQueue() {
  if (requestQueue.length === 0) {
    isProcessing = false;
    return;
  }

  isProcessing = true;
  const firstEntry = requestQueue.shift();
  if (!firstEntry) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    filePath,
    res
  } = firstEntry;

  try {
    const solution = await useRunningPythonServer(filePath);
    console.log('solution: ', solution);
    res.status(200).send(solution);
    processQueue();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
    console.error(error);
    processQueue();
  }
}

async function handleFileUpload(req, res) {
  try {
    if (!pythonRunningProcess) {
      return res.status(500).send('python process is not running');
    }
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded');
    }
    if (Object.keys(req.files).length > 1) {
      return res.status(400).send('Provide a single file');
    }

    const imageFile = req.files.imageFile;
    const fileName = `image-${Date.now()}.png`;
    const filePath = path.join(downloadsFolder, fileName);
    console.log('filePath: ', filePath);

    // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
    imageFile.mv(filePath, async function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }

      requestQueue.push({
        filePath,
        res
      });

      if (isProcessing) {
        return;
      }

      processQueue();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
}

export function runNodeListenerServer() {
  const app = express();
  app.use(
    fileUpload({
      limits: {
        fileSize: 20 * 1024
      }, // 20 kb
    })
  );

  console.log('>>> runNodeListenerServer');
  const PORT = 3456;
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });

  // spawn python process  only once simultaneously with the server;
  // reuse it multiple times later
  spawnPythonProcess();

  app.get('/recognise-image', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('python process is running'));
  app.post('/recognise-image', handleFileUpload);
}

runNodeListenerServer();
```

Regarding the 2nd - Python is an interpreted language, so each time you run a python script, it will go over all lines from the top. In my case, I decided to comment out the entire file, and to temporarily `print("someText")` inside it to see how long it takes to run. The invocation was almost instant.
Then I started uncommenting code line by line and realised the `import torch` is the slowest one and takes around 2 seconds.

You also might find it helpful how to benchmark the duration of scripts execution. In windows PowerShell use:

```
Write-Output "$(Get-Date)"; npx ts-node --transpileOnly src/recognise-image.ts; Write-Output "$(Get-Date)"
```

In bash, use:

```bash
date && npx ts-node --transpileOnly src/recognise-image.ts && date
```

My device spec just for the reference: Win 11 Pro, Ryzen 7 5800H, 3.20 GHz, 32 GB RAM. On another device I use (MacBook Pro M1) the numbers are completely different - the child process is invoked almost instantly even with Python imports.

Good luck with combining it all together!